# How to handle constant term in Least Squares Regression?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

In the well known matrix form of a least squares regression

where I am trying to solve for **B** in Y = B1X1 + B2X2 + B3

I might be given X and Y sample data as something like

$X$ = 
$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

$Y$ = 
$\begin{bmatrix} 
7 \\
8 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

In such an arrangement how do I include B3?  I would think I would want to add it in as always 1 in **X**

IE

$X$ = 
$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
2 & 3 \\ 
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Sorry if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the sample data is represented as a 'design matrix' $X$ in which each row represents one training vector. For your $X$ it would look like this:

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 3 & 1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

In general, you need to insert column of $1$'s as the first (or last) column in you design matrix.

The $X$ you proposed would be correct if each column, not row, represented a training example.

Comment: Thanks Blazej.  Later today I will try it out and confirm then I will certainly accept the answer.   BTW you are spot on I transposed the training vectors for some reason......Thanks again.